# how to remove row having some character in column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove a row from a table, where a specific column contains a specific value in it (e.g., a character) ?

I'd like to remove all the rows that contain the character 'a' in the column 'name'

Comment: A: DELETE with  LIKE.

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort btw.

Comment: Permanemtly?  Delete from table where name like '%a%'  this deletes with at least a 'a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a 'delete' statement combined with a 'like' clause. 
Example:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE [column] LIKE '% a %';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

> Notice the WHERE clause in the SQL DELETE statement! The WHERE clause
>   specifies which record or records that should be deleted. If you omit
>   the WHERE clause, all records will be deleted!

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

The SQL LIKE Operator
The LIKE operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column.

SQL LIKE Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;
```

[and here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)